# How to display data from XMLHttpRequest inside another var?

Tags: javascript, php

userIP.php

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>
```

Now I'm trying to use a callback using javascript but I can't seem to display the data somewhere else.

This is how I am retriving the data..

```
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("get", "userIP.php", true);
    oReq.send(null);
    oReq.onload = function()
    {
        document.write(this.responseText);
    };
```

It does display my IP..

but how can I use that data from oReq inside this var?

```
var params = "&user_ip=" + HERE + "&user_agent=" + navigator.userAgent;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

Since the `params` variable is set before the initial request is finished, the data ends up being undefined. The fix is to set it after the request as seen here: 
http://pastebin.com/Cd8KkH5g

---

**OLD ANSWER:**

I haven't tested this yet, so I hope it works.

Create a variable outside of the onload function

`var loadedText;`

Replace the function with

`oReq.onload = function()
{
   loadedText = this.responseText;
};`

Then use the variable inside of your parameters.

`var params = "&user_ip=" + loadedText + "&user_agent=" + navigator.userAgent;`

Comment: Oh right, because the loadedText is being changed after it's already been used.

Comment: You'll have to call a function at the end of the `onload` function that updates `params`.

Comment: So since you're waiting on `loadedText` to be initialized with data, that's your bottleneck. Try putting everything after the `onload()` function into it's own and call it after `loadedText` is set.

Comment: For some reason it still didn't work even after putting the code after onload.

Comment: this is some stripped down code, but it seems to be working for me. http://pastebin.com/Cd8KkH5g

Comment: That's interesting, it worked.. although I had tried it in a similar way.. sigh.. thank you anthony! Will study this a bit more and see where I went wrong.